# Performing a foreach in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I am trying to do a foreach loop where it would select each string in my array and add it to the path which is a string and stores the path for the image, this is what I have so far:

```
string[] Images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png" };
string Path = "Assets/Images/";

        if (LevelUp)
        {
            foreach()
            {

            }
        }
```

As you can see I want the foreach loop to go through each string in the Images array, for each string in the Images array I want it to be added to the path string so the end result for example would be "Assets/Images/Star_00001.png"

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Comment: What would you want to do with `Star_00002.png`? You've only shown a result for `Star_00001.png`. What have you *tried* with the `foreach` loop? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet That was just an example dude to give people the jist

Comment: But you *didn't* give us the gist of it. If you're going to give an example (which is good), do it properly. You've said that the result should be "Assets/Images/Star_00001.png" - that isn't adding *each string* in the Images array... it's just adding the first one. I've still no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, whats strange is, 4 people have understood what I am trying to achieve! Since I want to incorporate a foreach loop and it says "for example" in the question, isn't it common sense to think I want it done for every string?

Comment: @JermainDefo: well most have included "*do something*", and there are differences in what they do. JoelCoehorn for instance creates a new array whereas the others leave it open if you want to do that...

Comment: Not making assumptions about what's clear in your question, and checking over your phrasing, will generally improve the quality of answers and cause people to write *specifically* what you need. They may even be able to suggest a one-line God Function for doing everything you need. I get the vague idea your needs could be solved by a LINQ function, but I still have no idea what your needs are.

Comment: You've got three different answers doing three different things. That wouldn't have happened if you had been clear. I don't see how they can *all* understand what you're trying to achieve, as they've achieved different things.

Comment: @JonSkeet And you'd know that they're wrong answers because you know what I am trying to achieve? I think tbh 2 out of the 3 answers were correct, they both work perfectly fine as I expected. Anything else you want to point out?

Comment: I don't know which of them is right, because you *still* haven't said what you're trying to achieve. (And no two of them give you the code to do the same think. Frank and Joel's answers are similar, but not actually the same.) I still don't know why you didn't just fix the question to make it clearer. Do you understand that people want to help you, but that you're making it hard for them to do so? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints before you ask your next question - or preferrably right now, fixing your current question.

Answer (score 1):

A [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop has the syntax:

```
foreach(T ident in collection) {
```

with `T` the type of the elements, `ident` the name of the variable and `collection` an object that supports the `IEnumerable` interface.

So you can implement:

```
string[] images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png" };
string path = "Assets/Images/";
if (LevelUp) {
    foreach(string file in images) {
        string thepath = Path.Combine(path,file);
        //do something with file or thepath, like
        Console.WriteLine(thepath);
    }
}
```

A final note is that C#'s consensus is that variables start with a lowercase and type names with an uppercase.

Comment: @stuartd: that's why I made it start with a lower case which is also adviced by the C# standard...

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] Images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png" };
string path = "Assets/Images/";

if (LevelUp) 
    Images = Images.Select(image => Path.Combine(path, image)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to generate file paths by using string concatenation. The recommended way is to use Path.Combine which is provided in System.IO. Consider the example below:

```
        string[] Images = new string[] { "Star_00001.png", "Star_00002.png", "Star_00003.png" };
        string path = "Assets/Images/";

        if (LevelUp)
        {
            foreach (string s in Images)
            {
                // You can store result in an array or sth depending on what you
                // are trying to achieve
                string result = Path.Combine(path, s);
            }
        }
```